# Scientific Notation storage Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.5, and I am trying to figure out how to store data in the  "long" or "scientific notation" format. For example, in excel, I have a number `42540528726795050063891204319802818560`, which shows up as `4.2540768075074E+37` in the column. How do I properly store this number in Postgres so that I can query it as a number, sort it, perform calculations on it, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this below link for the required documentation.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html

NUMERIC datatype can accept an integer with digit length upto 131072 digits before the decimal point.